# Is it possible to run a timer in background in Java?

Tags: java, timer

I wanted to run a timer in background in Java, starting from the moment a message is displayed or printed on the terminal to the the moment the user presses enter after inputting a string. Is it possible to do so? If yes, then how?

Comment: By *run a timer*, are you just looking to get the time difference?

Comment: `java.util.Timer` automatically runs in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code to get time elapsed in seconds for the user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StopWatchDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type a message: ");

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        double elapsedSeconds = (end - start) / 1000.0;
        System.out.println("User input: " + input);
        System.out.println("Time taken (sec): " + elapsedSeconds);
    }
}
```

**Run output:**

```
Please type a message: 
This is a user message <press Enter key>
User input: This is a user message
Time taken (sec): 10.106
```